# Mongo Atlas error “cannot find user account after reload”

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I’m getting this error when accessing MongoDB Atlas from my Spring Boot app:

```
{
    "ok": 0,
    "errmsg": "cannot find user account after reload",
    "code": 8000,
    "codeName": "AtlasError"
}
```

I couldn’t find any topic about this exact error message. Does anybody know, what does it mean?

UPDATE:
I have filled an issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/3584